# Log4j, patternLayout, class and category

Tags: configuration, log4j, pattern-layout

I am having trouble establishing the exact difference between using those two log4j conversion characters when used in a **log4j PatternLayout** ([log4j patternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html))

- **category (%c)**
- **class (%C)**

Can someone please give me an example where those two would be different?

Doesn't the category always match the class name?

Regards,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will be the same if you initialize the logger in the popular way suggested by the documentation, and use it inside the `X` class:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.foo.X.class);
```

then you'll get the same for `%c` and `%C`, because logger name (constructed by "com.foo.X.class.getName()") would match the class name where a **logging statement was issued**.

Call your logger "something"

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("something");
```

and you'll have "something" for `%c` and the class name for `%C`.

Note that `%C` is computed by log4j out of the current thread's stack trace, so it carries big performance impact, unlike `%c`, which is simply a String. You can conduct an interesting experiment to validate it:

```java
package com.foo;

class A {
     private Logger = Logger.getLogger(B.class);
     // ...
     logger.log("inside A class");
}
```

The output for pattern `[%c][%m]` assuming `B` is in package `com.foo` will be:

```
[com.foo.B][inside A class]
```

The output for pattern `[%C][%m]` regardless of the location of `B` will be:

```
[com.foo.A][inside A class]
```